# Local Save Files in Co-Op on Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to buy Borderlands 2, but I want to play with my brother, but when I played in a friend's house, the game just saved his character, and didn't save mine. Is it possible to save player2's character? (Sorry if I wrote something wrong, i'm brazilian)

Comment: Hi, Lucas, and welcome to Arqade!  Nice post.  One question I have is what platform are you planning to play on, and what platform is your friend using?  It seems like it's either XBox 360 or PS3, but the clarification would be helpful.

Comment: I'm buying for PS3 but I played on XBOX

Comment: Short of a save file converter program (don't think there is one for BL2) I don't think you'll be able to transfer to a different console.

Comment: I know, but I want to know if player 2 also have save files.

Comment: @LucasFontenele: I don't know how you would go about this on a PS3, but on the 360, I think the second player needs to be at least signed into a profile, if not XBox Live proper for game progress to be saved (and possibly played).

Comment: Nevermind, I discovered what was the problem, forgot to select player two's profile.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to save player2's character?

Yes, that is normally what happens.  I play split screen and both characters get saved.

Each player chooses a storage device when starting a game.  The character data will be loaded from and saved to that storage device.

If I started a game and picked the xbox360 hard drive, my character data on the flash drive wouldn't be loaded and the game would think I have no characters.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened the first time my brother and I played it on PS3.The way to fix this is to create a separate profile for player 2 and use that every time you want to play local co-op. NEVER play on the same profile, only one of the characters will be saved!